# Finding $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $f(a,y)=f(b,y)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, $a \neq b$.
Assume that $f(a,y)=f(b,y)=1$.

> Is it true that $f(x,y)=(x-a)(x-b)g(x,y)+1$, for some $g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

It is clear that if $f(x,y)=(x-a)(x-b)g(x,y)+1$, for some $g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, then $f(a,y)=f(b,y)=1$, but what about the opposite direction?

**Remark:** We can consider $h(x,y):=f(x,y)-1$, and so $h(a,y)=h(b,y)=0$.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Presumably your assumption is "$f(a,y)=f(b,y)=1$ for all $y\in\mathbb C$", not just for a single $y$. What happens if you do long division of $f(x,y)$ by $x-a$, treating them as polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C[y]$?

Comment: Hint: write $f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0} p_i(x)y^i$. What can you conclude by comparing terms with the same $y$-degree?

Comment: @GregMartin, yes, my assumption is that $f(a,y)=f(b,y)=1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why don't you try proving the result by contradiction.It can be useful.

Comment: @KReiser, from $1=f(a,y)=\sum_{i=0} p_i(a)y^i$, $1=f(b,y)=\sum_{i=0} f_i(b)y^i$, we get that $p_i(a)=p_i(b)=0$, for every $i \geq 1$, so $f(x,y)= p_0(x)$?

Comment: We have: (1) $p_0(a)=p_0(b)=1$. (2) $p_i(a)=p_i(b)=0$ for every $i \geq 1$, hence $p_i=(x-a)(x-b)r_i$ for some $r_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Therefore, $f(x,y)=p_0+\sum_{i \geq 1} (x-a)(x-b)r_i y^i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse also holds.

Let $f(x,y) =\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x^i y^j = (x-a)Q(x,y) + P(y) $, for some polys P and Q. Since $f(a,y) = 1  \forall y $, $P(y) = 1, \forall y$ follows.

So $f(x,y) = (x-a)Q(x,y) + 1$

Playing the same game with $b$ and $Q(x,y)$ yields that $$f(x,y) = (x-a)((x-b)H(x,y) + G(y))+1= (x-a)(x-b)H(x,y) + (x-a)G(y)+1.$$ Since $f(b,y)=1, \forall y$ it follows that $(b-a)G(y)=0$ $\forall y$ so $G=0$ since $b \neq a$.

So $f(x,y) = (x-a)(x-b)H(x,y) + 1 $ as desired.